# spring boot auto restart cause CommandLineRunner null exception

Tags: java, spring

I define a `CommandLineRunner` after application run then create a root account.

code like

```
public class AdminTask implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private AdminRepository adminRepository;

    @Autowired
    private AdminService adminService;

    @Override
    public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {

     Admin root = adminRepository.findByUsername("root");
       if (root == null) {
           Log.debug("创建管理员账号");
            root = new Admin();
            root.setUsername("root");
            root.setEmail("root@123.com");
            adminService.createAdmin(root, "asdqwe123");
        }
    }

}
```

And I change the jpa driver as `spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.p6spy.engine.spy.P6SpyDriver`

I define the `P6spyListener` to listen  jdbcevent

```java
 @Override
    public void onAfterExecuteQuery(PreparedStatementInformation statementInformation, long timeElapsedNanos, SQLException e) {
        App.sqlCount.set(App.sqlCount.get() + 1);
        Long duration = timeElapsedNanos / 1000000;
        App.sqlDuration.set(App.sqlDuration.get() + duration);
        Log.info(String.format("执行sql || %s 耗时 %s ms", statementInformation.getSqlWithValues(), duration));
    }

    @Override
    public void onAfterExecuteUpdate(PreparedStatementInformation statementInformation, long timeElapsedNanos, int rowCount, SQLException e) {
        App.sqlCount.set(App.sqlCount.get() + 1);
        Long duration = timeElapsedNanos / 1000000;
        App.sqlDuration.set(App.sqlDuration.get() + duration);
        String singleLineSql = statementInformation.getSqlWithValues().replaceAll("\n", "\\\\n");
        Log.info(String.format("执行sql || %s 耗时 %s ms", singleLineSql, duration));
    }
```

the App object used to store per request thread info.

```java
public class App {

    public static final String SESSION_USER = "user"; // 用户对象
    public static ThreadLocal<String> _uniq_req_no = new ThreadLocal<String>();
    public static ThreadLocal<Integer> sqlCount = new ThreadLocal<Integer>();
    public static ThreadLocal<Long> sqlDuration = new ThreadLocal<Long>();

    static {
        sqlCount.set(0);
        sqlDuration.set(0L);
        _uniq_req_no = new ThreadLocal<String>();
        _uniq_req_no.set("");
    }

}
```

everything run ok. bug get a null execption  `App.sqlCount.set(App.sqlCount.get() + 1);` on this line only when save file auto restart.

Comment: Ofcourse. It starts with no value so the first one will be `null + 1` due to autoboxing this will throw a nullpointer exception. Instead of get and set I strongly recommend to use an `AtomicInt` or `AtomicLong` and use `incrementAndGet` or the likes to have 1 operation. ANd to initialize it properly. Using `ThreadLocal.withInitial(() -> new AtomicLong(0));` or the likes. BUt shouldn't the P6Spy yu are using already record all that information? Seems a bit lame you need to do that yourself?

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks for reply.  yes , P6Spy already record per sql execute time , but i want count the sql and total time then record it after the request finish. like `2021-03-02 19:15:39.168 || 869713e0-139c-47b4-a8bb-e26835463a50 || INFO  || c.v.i.c.R.afterCompletion:39 ||  finish request... || sql count:0 sql total druation :0 ms`

Comment: Which will only work for a single request, unless you clear/reset the thread locals.